# Is there any way to make Android SDK's device emulator to emulate an ARMv7 device?

Tags: android, arm, coronasdk

By default AVD runs ARMv6, is there any way to make it emulate an ARMv7 device?

Answer (score 0):

There is the ability to download an "ARM EABI v7a System Image" via the 'SDK Manager tool' (this is in the 4.2 API product tree).  Then you will need to create an emulator, that uses this system image.

If the image you are looking for doesn't exist (you aren't seeing it in the list of downloadable options in the SDK Manager) it probably isn't possible right now.

Bottom line, you will need the ARMv7 system image - then you can use that in your emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done it, but there was talk on the forums about setting the emulator up to emulate a Google Nexus 7 tablet and that would install the ARM 7 support.  I can't find that post, but here is a post that has a walk through:

https://developer.coronalabs.com/forum/2012/10/26/guide-getting-your-corona-app-run-android-emulator