# android can't load SupportV8 RenderScript in api <17

Tags: android, crash, android-support-library, renderscript

i just want to use RenderScript's ScriptIntrinsicBlur in my application , i've added renderscript.v8.jar (in android support lib v8) for supporting under 17 apis but it crashes on this line (in api <17 this happens it works fine on 4.2 or higher) :

```
        RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(getApplicationContext());
```

and the Exception output is

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
 Caused by: android.support.v8.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: Error loading RS jni library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load RSSupport: findLibrary returned null
        at android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript.create(RenderScript.java:945)
        at android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript.create(RenderScript.java:982)
        at android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript.create(RenderScript.java:968)
```

anyone has any idea how can i handle this ?

Comment: Adding the jar is not sufficient. On Eclipse use _renderscript.support.mode=true_ instead  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html#access-rs-apis . Maybe there's similar flag for Android Studio these days too - using which installs required native libraries also.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll need to tell Eclipse or Android Studio to use RenderScript support mode.

In Eclipse, edit your `project.properties` file and add:

`renderscript.target=18
renderscript.support.mode=true`

In Android Studio, edit your `build.gradle` file in your app module and add this in the `defaultConfig` enclosure (see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html#ide-setup for details):

`renderscriptTargetApi 18
renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true`

The target API level there needs to be the max you can use.  If your minimum SDK level is higher, this value is ignored and the min SDK value is used instead.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about the issues you are seeing.

Comment: What solved my issue was switching to build tools 22.0.1 there was a missing library that wouldn't get packaged on newer build tools. You'd think google tests beforehand?

Comment: It's possible that the tools needed to be updated.  The Renderscript API value doesn't go in lock-step with Android API releases or tool versions.  Sometimes the kernel "form" you use can also be affected.  It can be quite confusing.  Google does test before they release, but it's nearly impossible to test for all possible devices, so things can slip through the cracks.  Often a tools update and rebuild will resolve an issue like this.

Comment: Also make sure you are actually importing `android.support.v8.renderscript` classes and not native `android.renderscript` classes. For me using native classes just displayed warning which I overlooked for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

It's interesting, that even the Android Renderscript examples wont work in an emulator, lets say with API 10. (Tested via Android Studio, recent updates, create Example, Emulator with API 10 -> Crash). That's surprising. 
At my project, I did try/catch the Renderscript and take a fallback to at least do not crash the app, if the single stupid blur effect, made with Renderscript, is not available. 
So we know, the shared library is missing on the device. That's why some people copy the Renderscript libraries to their project, usually the build tools would do the same. One could easily check this by having a look into the apk/zip file.
I think a good tutorial is given here: http://possiblemobile.com/2013/10/renderscript-for-all

Comment: Could you please add more details about your solution? Only a reference to the link won't be useful if it becomes invalid

Comment: My solution is just some fallback, because Renderscript was just used for a fancy effect. I found further information regarding the emulator issue: "RenderScript library only includes JNI library for armeabi-v7a, and 2.x emulators are only available with armeabi, which seems to be the problem." https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68520
Please have a look into your apk (open as zip file). There should be libraries "lib/[armeabi-v7a | mips | x86]/[librsjni.so | libRSSupport.so]". If this is the case, you cannot improve the result, since Google fixes this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458478/is-there-any-way-to-make-android-sdks-device-emulator-to-emulate-an-armv7-devic looks like it answers the question about getting an armv7 emulator. We don't support armeabi, nor do we plan to support armeabi, because the vast majority of legacy ARM devices (i.e. nearly all of them) are armv7 and not armeabi.