# Error when trying to blur image using RenderScript support library on android phone

Tags: android, bitmap, blur, renderscript

I'm trying to blur my image, and display it blurred on an RelativeLayout's background with RenderScript, the app works in the emulator but my app in the phone keeps crashing with this error:

> 08-05 22:21:36.543: E/RenderScript_jni(11549): No GC methods
>   08-05 22:21:36.553: D/dalvikvm(11549): No JNI_OnLoad found in /system/lib/libRSSupport.so 0x41803ab8, skipping init
>   08-05 22:21:36.557: E/dalvikvm(11549): ERROR: couldn't find native method
>   08-05 22:21:36.557: E/dalvikvm(11549): Requested: Landroid/support/v8/renderscript/RenderScript;._nInit:()V
>   08-05 22:21:36.558: E/JNIHelp(11549): RegisterNatives failed for 'android/support/v8/renderscript/RenderScript', aborting
>   08-05 22:21:36.558: A/libc(11549): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 11549 (m.example.login)

Here is my blur code on a seperate class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v8.renderscript.*;

public class Blur {
    public static Bitmap blurBitmap(Context context, Bitmap src) {
        Bitmap outBitmap = src.copy(src.getConfig(), true);

        final RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(context);
        final Allocation input = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, src);
        final Allocation output = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, outBitmap);

        final ScriptIntrinsicBlur script =
                ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
        script.setRadius(25f);
        script.setInput(input);
        script.forEach(output);
        output.copyTo(outBitmap);

        rs.destroy();

        return outBitmap;
    }
}
```

and here is ny code in the MainActivity (I'm getting the Bitmap from the Gallery):

```
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
Blur blur = new Blur();
imagepath = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);
Bitmap BlurredIMG = Blur.blurBitmap(getApplicationContext(), bmImg);
BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable(BlurredIMG);
rl.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
```

Comment: I think the problem is with `Allocation` definitions: try this => `final Allocation input = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, src, Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE, Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT); final Allocation output = Allocation.createTyped(rs, input.getType());`.

Comment: @Vikram 08-05 22:49:46.664: E/RenderScript_jni(12305): No GC methods
08-05 22:49:46.750: D/dalvikvm(12305): No JNI_OnLoad found in /system/lib/libRSSupport.so 0x417ff3e8, skipping init
08-05 22:49:46.775: E/dalvikvm(12305): ERROR: couldn't find native method
08-05 22:49:46.775: E/dalvikvm(12305): Requested: Landroid/support/v8/renderscript/RenderScript;._nInit:()V
08-05 22:49:46.776: E/JNIHelp(12305): RegisterNatives failed for 'android/support/v8/renderscript/RenderScript', aborting
08-05 22:49:46.776: A/libc(12305): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 12305 (m.example.l)

Comment: The same error - can you try after removing the `rs.destroy()` call?

Comment: same error again @Vikram

Comment: @Vikram It's weird because on my first code, the app ran good on the emulator but on my Android phone not.
my emulator version: 4.4.2
my phone version: 4.1.1

Comment: Yea, that's weird. I'm sure someone from android renderscript team will help you with this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue. After hours of researching I've found another [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10028267/3903464). It works very fast *(around 10-15ms)* if pre-scale image vertically and horizontally and then apply this algorithm.
My solution looks like this

```
//here we scale bitmap and apply blur
private Bitmap blur(Bitmap bkg) {

            float scaleFactor = 8;
            int radius = 2;
            int inputWidth = bkg.getWidth();
            int inputHeight = bkg.getHeight();

            Bitmap overlay = Bitmap.createBitmap((int)(inputWidth/scaleFactor),(int)(inputHeight/scaleFactor), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(overlay);

            canvas.scale(1 / scaleFactor, 1 / scaleFactor);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setFlags(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);

            canvas.drawBitmap(bkg, 0, 0, paint);

            //  bkg.recycle();
            overlay = FastBlur.doBlur(overlay, radius, true);
            return getResizedBitmap(overlay, inputWidth, inputHeight, true);

        }


        public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth, boolean willDelete) {

            int width = bm.getWidth();

            int height = bm.getHeight();

            float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;

            float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

            // CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION

            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

            // RESIZE THE BIT MAP

            matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

            // RECREATE THE NEW BITMAP

            Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);

            //          if(willDelete)
            //              bm.recycle();

            return resizedBitmap;
        }
```

At last this is my class which wraps blur algorithm

```
public class FastBlur {

    public static Bitmap doBlur(Bitmap sentBitmap, int radius, boolean canReuseInBitmap) {

        // Stack Blur v1.0 from
        // http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html
        //
        // Java Author: Mario Klingemann <mario at quasimondo.com>
        // http://incubator.quasimondo.com
        // created Feburary 29, 2004
        // Android port : Yahel Bouaziz <yahel at kayenko.com>
        // http://www.kayenko.com
        // ported april 5th, 2012

        // This is a compromise between Gaussian Blur and Box blur
        // It creates much better looking blurs than Box Blur, but is
        // 7x faster than my Gaussian Blur implementation.
        //
        // I called it Stack Blur because this describes best how this
        // filter works internally: it creates a kind of moving stack
        // of colors whilst scanning through the image. Thereby it
        // just has to add one new block of color to the right side
        // of the stack and remove the leftmost color. The remaining
        // colors on the topmost layer of the stack are either added on
        // or reduced by one, depending on if they are on the right or
        // on the left side of the stack.
        //
        // If you are using this algorithm in your code please add
        // the following line:
        //
        // Stack Blur Algorithm by Mario Klingemann <mario@quasimondo.com>

        Bitmap bitmap;
        if (canReuseInBitmap) {
            bitmap = sentBitmap;
        } else {
            bitmap = sentBitmap.copy(sentBitmap.getConfig(), true);
        }

        if (radius < 1) {
            return (null);
        }

        int w = bitmap.getWidth();
        int h = bitmap.getHeight();

        int[] pix = new int[w * h];
        bitmap.getPixels(pix, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);

        int wm = w - 1;
        int hm = h - 1;
        int wh = w * h;
        int div = radius + radius + 1;

        int r[] = new int[wh];
        int g[] = new int[wh];
        int b[] = new int[wh];
        int rsum, gsum, bsum, x, y, i, p, yp, yi, yw;
        int vmin[] = new int[Math.max(w, h)];

        int divsum = (div + 1) >> 1;
        divsum *= divsum;
        int dv[] = new int[256 * divsum];
        for (i = 0; i < 256 * divsum; i++) {
            dv[i] = (i / divsum);
        }

        yw = yi = 0;

        int[][] stack = new int[div][3];
        int stackpointer;
        int stackstart;
        int[] sir;
        int rbs;
        int r1 = radius + 1;
        int routsum, goutsum, boutsum;
        int rinsum, ginsum, binsum;

        for (y = 0; y < h; y++) {
            rinsum = ginsum = binsum = routsum = goutsum = boutsum = rsum = gsum = bsum = 0;
            for (i = -radius; i <= radius; i++) {
                p = pix[yi + Math.min(wm, Math.max(i, 0))];
                sir = stack[i + radius];
                sir[0] = (p & 0xff0000) >> 16;
                sir[1] = (p & 0x00ff00) >> 8;
                sir[2] = (p & 0x0000ff);
                rbs = r1 - Math.abs(i);
                rsum += sir[0] * rbs;
                gsum += sir[1] * rbs;
                bsum += sir[2] * rbs;
                if (i > 0) {
                    rinsum += sir[0];
                    ginsum += sir[1];
                    binsum += sir[2];
                } else {
                    routsum += sir[0];
                    goutsum += sir[1];
                    boutsum += sir[2];
                }
            }
            stackpointer = radius;

            for (x = 0; x < w; x++) {

                r[yi] = dv[rsum];
                g[yi] = dv[gsum];
                b[yi] = dv[bsum];

                rsum -= routsum;
                gsum -= goutsum;
                bsum -= boutsum;

                stackstart = stackpointer - radius + div;
                sir = stack[stackstart % div];

                routsum -= sir[0];
                goutsum -= sir[1];
                boutsum -= sir[2];

                if (y == 0) {
                    vmin[x] = Math.min(x + radius + 1, wm);
                }
                p = pix[yw + vmin[x]];

                sir[0] = (p & 0xff0000) >> 16;
                sir[1] = (p & 0x00ff00) >> 8;
                sir[2] = (p & 0x0000ff);

                rinsum += sir[0];
                ginsum += sir[1];
                binsum += sir[2];

                rsum += rinsum;
                gsum += ginsum;
                bsum += binsum;

                stackpointer = (stackpointer + 1) % div;
                sir = stack[(stackpointer) % div];

                routsum += sir[0];
                goutsum += sir[1];
                boutsum += sir[2];

                rinsum -= sir[0];
                ginsum -= sir[1];
                binsum -= sir[2];

                yi++;
            }
            yw += w;
        }
        for (x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            rinsum = ginsum = binsum = routsum = goutsum = boutsum = rsum = gsum = bsum = 0;
            yp = -radius * w;
            for (i = -radius; i <= radius; i++) {
                yi = Math.max(0, yp) + x;

                sir = stack[i + radius];

                sir[0] = r[yi];
                sir[1] = g[yi];
                sir[2] = b[yi];

                rbs = r1 - Math.abs(i);

                rsum += r[yi] * rbs;
                gsum += g[yi] * rbs;
                bsum += b[yi] * rbs;

                if (i > 0) {
                    rinsum += sir[0];
                    ginsum += sir[1];
                    binsum += sir[2];
                } else {
                    routsum += sir[0];
                    goutsum += sir[1];
                    boutsum += sir[2];
                }

                if (i < hm) {
                    yp += w;
                }
            }
            yi = x;
            stackpointer = radius;
            for (y = 0; y < h; y++) {
                // Preserve alpha channel: ( 0xff000000 & pix[yi] )
                pix[yi] = (0xff000000 & pix[yi]) | (dv[rsum] << 16) | (dv[gsum] << 8) | dv[bsum];

                rsum -= routsum;
                gsum -= goutsum;
                bsum -= boutsum;

                stackstart = stackpointer - radius + div;
                sir = stack[stackstart % div];

                routsum -= sir[0];
                goutsum -= sir[1];
                boutsum -= sir[2];

                if (x == 0) {
                    vmin[y] = Math.min(y + r1, hm) * w;
                }
                p = x + vmin[y];

                sir[0] = r[p];
                sir[1] = g[p];
                sir[2] = b[p];

                rinsum += sir[0];
                ginsum += sir[1];
                binsum += sir[2];

                rsum += rinsum;
                gsum += ginsum;
                bsum += binsum;

                stackpointer = (stackpointer + 1) % div;
                sir = stack[stackpointer];

                routsum += sir[0];
                goutsum += sir[1];
                boutsum += sir[2];

                rinsum -= sir[0];
                ginsum -= sir[1];
                binsum -= sir[2];

                yi += w;
            }
        }

        bitmap.setPixels(pix, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);

        return (bitmap);
    }

}
```

With best regards

Comment: Thanks, it works on the emulator again but on my phone I got OutOfMemoey error on this line: int[] pix = new int[w * h];
What should I do?

Comment: it didn't work on your last comment but I just wrote a code that downscaling the image and then blurs it.
your blur class is really fast. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Check your `build.gradle` file (Android Studio) or project.properties (Eclipse).  This sounds like you do not have it set to include RS support mode and targeted API level correctly.  See the answer here: [android can't load SupportV8 RenderScript in api <17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082537/android-cant-load-supportv8-renderscript-in-api-17/25091919#25091919)

Answer (score 0):

This code work perfect for me.

and setRadius between 0 to 23.

like "blur.setRadius(21)"

```
Bitmap tempbg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.b1); //Load a  background.
Bitmap final_Bitmap = BlurImage(tempbg);

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
Bitmap BlurImage (Bitmap input)
{
    try
    {
    RenderScript  rsScript = RenderScript.create(getApplicationContext());
    Allocation alloc = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rsScript, input);

    ScriptIntrinsicBlur blur = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rsScript, Element.U8_4(rsScript));
    blur.setRadius(21);
    blur.setInput(alloc);

    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(input.getWidth(), input.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Allocation outAlloc = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rsScript, result);

    blur.forEach(outAlloc);
    outAlloc.copyTo(result);

    rsScript.destroy();
    return result;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        return input;
    }

}
```