# Android 2.3.5 support library render script doesn't work

Tags: android, renderscript

On Android 3.0+ RenderScript works great. Here Im using buildin renderscript framework.

But if Im trying to lunch the same script on Android 2.3.5 with support library Im getting an exception

```
Caused by: android.support.v8.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: Error loading RS jni library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load RSSupport: findLibrary returned null
```

My project.property file is

```
target=android-10 renderscript.target=21 renderscript.support.mode=true sdk.buildtools=21.1.0
```

How should I integrate the RenderScript library with android 2.3.5 ? 
Thx, in advance.

Comment: I've done all of this things and unfortunatelly spent all day trying to launch renderscript on 2.2. No results for now

Comment: Try to use renderscript.target=18
For more details see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082537/android-cant-load-supportv8-renderscript-in-api-17