# Android: Renderscript error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, renderscript

I want blur to `ImageView` in Eclipse

But after run application error and crashed

```
SKD version = 24
```

> My code :

```
ScriptIntrinsicBlur theIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(renderScript, Element.U8_4(renderScript));
```

> Log :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.renderscript.ScriptIntrinsicBlur
BlurBuilder.blur(BlurBuilder.java:24)

PageActivity$1.run(PageActivity.java:166)

java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

How can solved this problem ?

Comment: Can help me ?! Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082537/android-cant-load-supportv8-renderscript-in-api-17

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36359235/2825313